# Apache CXF Plugin - Failure Generating Client

Tags: java, apache, maven, wsdl, cxf

I am trying to generate a webservice client using the Apache CXF Maven plugin but I am running into errors.
I just have a very simple maven project setup in eclipse
The wsdl file is located here - http://api.zenfolio.com/api/1.8/zfapi.asmx?wsdl

The pom file I am using is as follows

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>WebserviceClientGenerator</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <cxf.plugin.version>3.1.4</cxf.plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/src/main/java/com/test</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>http://api.zenfolio.com/api/1.8/zfapi.asmx?wsdl</wsdl> 
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>                          
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run a maven install on this pom file, I get the following error

```
    [ERROR] http://api.zenfolio.com/api/1.8/zfapi.asmx?wsdl [1559:11]: undefined simple or complex type 'soapenc:Array'
org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: http://api.zenfolio.com/api/1.8/zfapi.asmx?wsdl; systemId: http://api.zenfolio.com/api/1.8/zfapi.asmx?wsdl; lineNumber: 1559; columnNumber: 11; undefined simple or complex type 'soapenc:Array'
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$1.reportError(ParserContext.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.reportError(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.resolve(DelayedRef.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.run(DelayedRef.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.getResult(ParserContext.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.getResult(XSOMParser.java:214)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:538)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:460)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:726)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:270)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:415)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:415)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:260)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
```

Does anyone know if there is any configuration I make with the cxf plugin to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the WSDL uses a SOAP encoding, which is not supported by Apache CXF (or any current technology for that matter).

You have to rely on old SOAP stack, like Axis 1.x, that are the only one to handle such obsolete encoding. Using the [`axistools-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/) and Axis 1.4, you can generate a client stub for the WSDL:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-client</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <urls>
                    <url>http://api.zenfolio.com/api/1.8/zfapi.asmx?wsdl</url>
                </urls>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you need to add Axis 1.4 as a compile-time dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The generated client will be located in `target/generated-sources/axistools/wsdl2java` by default, but you can override that with the [`outputDirectory`](http://www.mojohaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/wsdl2java-mojo.html#outputDirectory) configuration element.